# How to split layout into frames and save data?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have to split my layout in two parts, something like that: [How to split an Android XML into three equal layout rectangles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779411/how-to-split-an-android-xml-into-three-equal-layout-rectangles)

But I want to work into these frames, maybe with text area and then going to save input text. How can I manage this frames?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to do? If all you want is to have controls inside of the rectangles, then do nested Layouts. i.e:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the text frame"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#00ff00" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="This is the editing frame"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#0000ff" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="This is the saving frame"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can add any view you need

Comment: yes but this are not frames... I want to create dynamically a frame to add a new one if I need (keep out another)

Comment: You mean fragments? In that case check this post [link]http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: and this one too [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)

Comment: but so, I have to decide only on xml where are the fragments? and then use each one as normal activity?

Comment: Well, that's the beauty of fragments! You can switch a fragment for another at anytime during runtime! It's called FragmentTransaction check the second link I posted above, everything is there

Comment: Now work the layout, but I have to refresh one fragment when I click on "add" into actionBar. that means that when I click "add/plus", I need a new fragment (empty) where the user will can add other input text

Comment: Create a new layout file with for the empty fragment. Then create a class extending Fragment and Override the method OnCreateView like this:

    `public class NewFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_new_layout, container, false);
        }
    }`

Comment: And on your onClick method of the actionbar button just make the fragment transaction.

        `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();`

        `FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();`

        `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.the_container_of_your_first_fragment, anInstanceOfYourNewFragment)`;
        `fragmentTransaction.commit();`
That should do the job.

Sorry for the bad formatting, comments are not the best for long code

Comment: Pleasure to help.
If the answer was useful please mark it